# Messages saved Kafka Topic not saving correctly via Kafka Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

So I have a Confluent Kafka JDBC connector set up. First I start up a schema registry such as

```
./bin/schema-registry-start ./etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

This is the schema-registery.properties file

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=zookeeperhost:2181
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://kafkahost:9092
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false
```

Next I start up a standalone connector like this

```
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./jdbc-source.properties
```

connect-avro-standalone.properties is

```
bootstrap.servers=kafkahost:9092

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
plugin.path=share/java
```

jdbc-source.properties is

```
name=jdbc_source_oracle
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SID=server)))
connection.user=xxx
connection.password=xxx
table.whitelist=table1, table2
mode=bulk
topic.prefix=my_topic
query=select * from table1 t1 join table1 t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t2.entereddate >='19-FEB-2019' and t2.entereddate <= '23-FEB-2019'
```

The query I am using is only for testing purposes, the real query I want to use will implement the incrementing mode and will contain no where clause.

Now this manages to publish data into the topic but with some weird stuff going on. First the IDs are saved in an unreadable format. Just empty square. Second some fields that are populated in the database are saving as null in the topic. And third, whenever I try to change the date in the query in the JDBC source file, nothing happens. It still contain the same messages I published the first time it ran, as in nothing in the kafka topic is updated no many how many times I change the query.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

What I want to do is consume the data through pyspark code. Here's the code on how I am doing it

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("data streaming app")\
    .getOrCreate()


data_raw = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafkahost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "my_topic")\
    .load()

query = data_raw.writeStream\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .format("console")\
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds")\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

I've also consume the data using the kafka-avro-console-consumer using this command

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer \
--bootstrap-server kafkahost:9092 \
--property print.key=true \
--from-beginning \
--topic my_topic
```

Both of these give me weird results

Here's what pyspark code is giving me
[image]

and this is what using the avro console is giving me

[image]

Blocking out some fields and text as it may contain company sensitive information.

Comment: Not clear how you are consuming the data. You need to use `kafka-avro-console-consumer`. Also, I believe timestamp incrementing mode needs at least second time precision, not string date columns

Comment: BTW if you're using `query` you don't need `table.whitelist`.

Comment: Also see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector

Comment: @cricket_007, I updated my post with information on how I am consuming from the topic, also i am  not using incrementing mode in this case. I am using bulk mode so that I can test out the functionality which is why I am using string data columns. Does this matter?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I tried not using table.whitelist before but I got this exception 
`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getTimestamp not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CClobAccessor`

I also looked through that link but cannot find anything that could help me

Comment: I've answered the points that I can, but without specific data and schema information it's hard to give much more detail around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're consuming Avro from Spark you'll need to use the [correct deserializer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html).

You're seeing bytes in your Avro data from the console then it's down to the handling of decimals/numerics, [as detailed here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#bytes-decimals-numerics).

You can read more about Kafka Connect and serialisation alternatives to Avro (including JSON) [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained).

Comment: This is for Scala, not sure if it will work for python. Is there a way for me to not use Avro when using the Kafka Connector? Or a Schema in general?

Comment: Yes you can use JsonConverter (or even StringConverter although why you'd want to do that is beyond me). I've added a link to my answer that will help you explain this

Comment: Note that you *can* consume Avro-serialised messages with Python: https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#avro / https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

Comment: @anonuser1234 You might want to try this for Spark output to the console https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks but that looks like its only for scala. I am working with PySpark

Comment: @anonuser1234 It's possible to import any Scala/Java Spark packages into PySpark. Just requires more configuration in the code. For example, the Kafka Streaming package is written in Scala, and you are using it in PySpark

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there an example of this somewhere I can see?